# Is there a want to find a duplicate values to in zip using python

Tags: python

**Is there a want to find a duplicate values to in zip using python**

I Have a zip values as such as

---

```
[(6, 0, 6, 1), (1, 8, 0, 3), (6, 10, 10, 8), (3, 6, 0, 4)]
```

I want to get an output as `[(6, 0, 6, 1), (6, 10, 10, 8)]`

I Have already tried doing `zip(x) if i.count(x) > 1`

Comment: I don't understand how this problem is related to `zip`? The way I see it, you just want to find tuples with duplicate elements in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
your_data = [(6, 0, 6, 1), (1, 8, 0, 3), (6, 10, 10, 8), (3, 6, 0, 4)]
filtered_data = [e for e in your_data if len(set(e)) < len(e)]
print(filtered_data)
```

(I'm assuming you want to filter the *results* of the zip, and not the original input.)

This is not the most efficient method, but it's clean;  we simply make a set (a collection of unique elements) out of each member of your list, and check whether it is shorter than the original member -- if it is, it had duplicates, and we <strike>drop</strike> keep it (thanks Aran-Fey!).

Comment: Thanks it is working perfectly

Comment: *"it had duplicates, and we drop it."* That's backwards. You *keep* those (: